The input cursor always stays on top in angular ionic
I have an angular application. I have added a capacitor to it and built an angular-ionic mobile app.
I am facing one particular issue in the input fields. The cursor of the input always stays on top of all other views.

THis issue is common for all input fields. I have tried different ways such as

Set up z-index
capacitor/keyboard- plugin usage.

But, no luck.
When I open my angular app in the mobile browser (responsive view), It works fine. It is more specific to the iOS application with ionic.
One solution I tried, remove focus when the page is scrolled, but the change would be large with a directive on all inputs.
Need help to investigate this further.

Can you please put a below style on input class:
margin-top: 2rem;

this should do your job. If you're using bootstrap, you can simply add a class on input:
class="mt-4"

